# Changing GitHub Pages url names

Tags: html, url, github-pages

I'm using Github Pages to host a simple three page site in plain HTML. Currently the other two pages besides the `index.html` have urls like `domain.com/assets/about.html` and `domain.com/assets/design.html`.

How can I get these pages of the site to show as simply `domain.com/about` and `domain.com/design`? I'm using a custom domain from GoDaddy on my Github Pages repo, if that's relevant.

The file structure is this:

```bash
.
├── index.html
└── assets/
    ├── about.html
    ├── design.html
    └── styles.css
```

And my buttons on each page have hrefs like this:

```html
<a class="nav-item" href="./assets/about.html">About</a>
<a class="nav-item" href="./index.html">Home</a>
<a class="nav-item" href="./assets/design.html">Design</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to these [Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site#next-steps) on Github Pages, `files will be available on your site in the same directory structure as your publishing source.`

To get rid of the `/assets/` part of the link, you should move the `about.html` and `design.html` out of the assets folder.

When doing so, don't forget to change the hrefs in your buttons.